# Error configuring Traefik TLS "Error configuring TLS for ingress secret does not exist"

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, traefik, kubernetes-secrets, kubernetes-helm

### Introduction

Configuring a new ingress-controller with Traefik using helm chart and creating secrets.

### Info

Kubernetes version: 1.9.3

Helm version: 2.9

Traefik chart version: 1.5

Traefik version: 1.7.2

### Problem

I am deploying Traefik through official helm chart, but always I have the same problem in the logs
`"Error configuring TLS for ingress default/traefik-testing-tls: secret default/traefik-tls does not exist"`

I have the secret properly created and configured in the same namespace and also checked the clusterrole and clusterrolebinds are ok and allows the access to secrets

I tried to change the `defaultCert` and `defaultKey` but not sure about this.

#### Configmap:

```
data:
traefik.toml: |
# traefik.toml
logLevel = "INFO"
defaultEntryPoints = ["http", "https", "httpn"]
[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
  compress = true
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
  compress = true
  [entryPoints.httpn]
  address = ":8880"
  compress = true
[kubernetes]
namespaces = ["default", "kube-system"]
[traefikLog]
  format = "json"
[accessLog]
  format = "common"
[accessLog.fields]
  defaultMode = "keep"
[accessLog.fields.names]
[accessLog.fields.headers]
  defaultMode = "keep"
[accessLog.fields.headers.names]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several checks, rbacs, namespaces, etc. a member from Traefik told us that the k8s objects are loaded asynchronously (so the ingress may be loaded before the secret) this is the reason because it gives a problem at start of the Traefik.

Comment: Does it load afterwards though?

Comment: It didn't in my case if waiting means less than 24h.

Comment: I had the same issue. My mistake was that I didn't use curl properly so it didn't send a proper SNI. With that it works, even though I get the cert error on when the container is created.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are missing the `traefik-tls` secret, for your `traefik-testing-tls` ingress, that probably holds your TLS certificates. You can follow [this](https://docs.traefik.io/user-guide/kubernetes/#add-a-tls-certificate-to-the-ingress).

Instead of:

```
kubectl -n kube-system create secret tls traefik-ui-tls-cert --key=tls.key --cert=tls.crt
```

You can use:

```
kubectl -n kube-system create secret tls traefik-tls --key=tls.key --cert=tls.crt
```

Comment: The secret is already created. This error is after created the secrets and added to the cluster